# react native maps customMapStyle return a blank map

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to setup GoogleMaps with custom styles. I did it on https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and got a json file. It works fine on my android emulator and on my ios device, but on my android device the map is blank. It has google logo at the bottom and my current location but noting else. If I remove customMapStyle line everything works fine.

I am wondering what could be the problem here. I am using expo so no separate android and ios folder.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I updated the expo app on the android device and it showed up. Weird

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).